# How do I write an regular express to find out if a filename contains ".pdf" at the end of the filename?

Tags: regex

How do I write a Perl regular express to find out if a filename contains a specific extension, for example ".pdf". The filename can be anything.

Comment: What on earth is a "PEAL regular express"?  Please proofread what you write.

Comment: Do you mean "Perl"? (Otherwise someone picked a really confusable name for their technology).

Comment: What language are you using? For example, in C# you can use `Path.GetFileExtension` and you dont even need a regex at all.

Comment: Maybe it's part of the BANANA Protocol?

Comment: This is really, really basic regex syntax. Please find and read a good reference. In fact, if that's all you're after, a regex is overkill.

Comment: Regex seems a bit overkill for this.  Why not just check the last 4 chars in the filename are ".pdf", depending on the language you are using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
if ($filename =~ /\.pdf$/) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Test the filename using the following regular expression: `\.pdf$`

Answer (score 0):

You don't, explode/split on the . and use the last item in the array/collection. This is usally better/faster than using a regex.